# SVG Image on a circle path

Tags: path, svg, raphael, gif, geometry

I would like to create a circular path that has animated .gifs along the path, though I would like them all to be facing the center of the circle.

I would also really like it if the circular path could scale with the window width and height.
Which would add or subtract .gifs to the circle.

Is this possible?

Example jpg..
http://oi48.tinypic.com/5nitt4.jpg

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. it's all possible, but please show some research effort and return to update your question to be more focused (once you encounter specific technological issues). you'd probably want to read the [FAQ entry on how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask), too. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think SVG supports animated .gifs. But everything else is possible--you just need a bit of trigonometry to position and scale your elements in the way you want them to be displayed!

*Edit*: As per the comments below, animated gifs are in fact supported.

Comment: Firefox and Opera will to animated gifs in SVG. I imagine most other UAs will too http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/MNN8t/

Comment: Chrome, Safari, and IE9 also support animated GIFs in SVG.

Comment: Thank you everyone, so could someone point me in the right direction?